# Autofill formulas in Macro from column A to last column

Tags: vba, dynamic, autofill

Im trying to Make a macro which will take the fomulas in cells B358 to B362 and autofill these rows to the last column used in row 2.

Im pretty new at VBA and completely selftaught by searching forums like this but unfortunately im not finding my solution.

Please help me

Edit:

If you need to see some code, i can give you a very basic example

```
Sub Macro1()

    Range("B358:B362").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B358:AHQ362"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("B358:AHQ362").Select
End Sub
```

In this example i would need the AutoFill destination to be (B358:"insert last column used in row 2 here"362)

Comment: It is always better and faster to improve your code... It is also preferred way of providing support here. Therefore please show the code you have at the moment. Did you try to do anything with macro recorder?

Comment: Well my problem is that i have basically nothing at all right now. Recording a macro will not give me much, mostly because i need it to be dynamic.

Comment: Do part of the job and we help you to get your code 'dynamic'. So, record some 'static' macro, show your code and we give you some tips. :)

Comment: ok so i added some code, sorry for it being jumbled, i didnt wirte it like that

Comment: great! see the answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is proposed dynamic solution in your situation:

```
Sub Macro1()


Dim lastCol As Long
lastCol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

 Range("B358:B362").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Range("B358"), Cells(362, lastCol)), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. ive been so close looking around at some other answers but since i dont understand most of the individual components i couldnt get it quite right. Thank you for your help